# Is it possible to run nodejs script by link on a web resource?

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to run a script on nodejs by link on a web resource?

For example:

```
node https://example.com/myscript.js
```

Comment: What is a "link"? (link on a webpage? symlink in a directory? desktop shortcut? etc. etc.) And more specifically, please remember to [explain yourself fully](/help/how-to-ask). Instead of writing a 10 word post, go into a bit of detail on what you're trying to do, what you tried in order to achieve that, how that didn't work, and where you got stuck figuring things out.

Comment: NodeJs is a backend (server) side code, from a web browser, you will never reach it... but what you can do is create an interface in the backend, for example, a http server that when a route get's reach, will execute whatever you want, and reply back...

Answer (score 0):

I would absolutely not recommend doing this but here you go

```
node -e "$(curl -s https://gist.githubusercontent.com/LEQADA/b52840e8a7e4ddbf92fada38aaecb350/raw/c03dd063e3f08d396a311dbb6a0ca9ba249967ae/random.js)"
```